# Is there a way to make Force Network D3 labels remain permanently, rather than hover over?

Tags: r, networkd3

Here is my program:

```r
networkD3::forceNetwork(Links = links.d3, Nodes = nodes.d3,
                        Source = "from", Target = "to", 
                        NodeID = "node_id", Group = "group_id",
                        zoom = TRUE, opacity = 1.0, legend = TRUE,
                        fontSize = 12)
```

Then I tried: 
`onRender(network, "function(el,x) { d3.selectAll('.node').on('mouseover', null); }")`

This just removes the labels all together. Ideally, I want to be able to click a node, and then have a node's label remain, after I hover away from it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `opacityNoHover = 1` as a parameter to the `forceNetwork()` function. This and all other options are in the help file (type `?networkD3::forceNetwork` in the console). That will make all the labels visible all the time.

If you want to prevent the labels from disappearing when you move the mouse away from the node, just modify your code to null the `mouseout` event instead of the `mouseover` event...
`onRender(network, "function(el,x) { d3.selectAll('.node').on('mouseout', null); }")`

---

UPDATE 2020.04.09

Here's a solution for making a click turn on or off the label for that node...

```r
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)
network <- 
  forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
               Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
               Group = "group", opacity = 1)

clickjs <- 
"function(el, x) { 
  var options = x.options;
  var svg = d3.select(el).select('svg');
  var node = svg.selectAll('.node');
  var link = svg.selectAll('link');
  var mouseout = d3.selectAll('.node').on('mouseout');
  function nodeSize(d) {
    if (options.nodesize) {
      return eval(options.radiusCalculation);
    } else {
      return 6;
    }
  }

  d3.selectAll('.node').on('click', onclick);

  function onclick(d) {
    if (d3.select(this).on('mouseout') == mouseout) {
      d3.select(this).on('mouseout', mouseout_clicked);
    } else {
      d3.select(this).on('mouseout', mouseout);
    }
  }

  function mouseout_clicked(d) {
    node.style('opacity', +options.opacity);
    link.style('opacity', +options.opacity);

    d3.select(this).select('circle').transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr('r', function(d){return nodeSize(d);});
    d3.select(this).select('text').transition()
      .duration(1250)
      .attr('x', 0)
      .style('font', options.fontSize + 'px ');
  }
}
"

onRender(network, clickjs)
```

[image]

Comment: The second solution worked perfectly, thank you so much.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so you can click on and off of a node? so the node labels stay up as needed? Instead of having to rerun each time?

Comment: Please see the update to my answer, and mark this as answered if it's an adequate solution.